# RedHat 6/Oracle Linux 6 is not allowing key authentication via ssh

Tags: redhat, selinux, sshd, oracle-enterprise-linux

Keys are properly deployed in ~/.ssh/authorized_keys

Yet ssh keeps on prompting for a password.

Comment: Check /var/log/secure it will have information if the public key failed for auth. Most likely file(s) have the wrong read/write permission in ~/.ssh.

Comment: In my case perms were fine. it was SELinux related, see below

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Several issues, mostly privileges - but also related to SELinux on RedHat 6

The following script should fix them all, please replace `<user>:<group>` with your matching userid and group

```
chown -R <user>:<group> ~/.ssh
chmod 700 ~/.ssh
chmod 600 ~/.ssh/*
restorecon -R -v ~/.ssh
```

Comment: you should not change the file permissions to be world readable even if they are inside a protected directory
`restorecon -R -v $HOME/.ssh` is what did the trick for me

Comment: Yes, it should be owner access only. In my rhel6 box still works with 600

Comment: You mean my suggestion was bad? because I see that you edited your response with 600 for the files.

Comment: forgot to update my comment, I had the file ownership wrong (note the chown addition). so your suggestion was fine.

Comment: Note that this only works for standard home directories.  If you are applying this change to a service account, or some other user whose home directory is not in /home, then you need to add the following command before restorecon (or rerun restorecon after running this command, replace path/to/service/home with the FULL home path):  semanage fcontext -a -t ssh_home_t "/path/to/service/home/\.ssh(/.*)?"

Answer (score 6):

I'd agree with the changes above working on most linux variants in the root account.
I have had a problem with RedHat 6.3 with trying to get a postgres user account to use DSA auth. (6.3 running in VirtualBox)

The issue can be that the basic selinux permissions are wrong. Restorecon wont help in this case.

```
(After restorecon)
drwx------. postgres postgres unconfined_u:object_r:var_lib_t:s0 .ssh
```

I have fixed this with :

```
chcon -R -t ssh_home_t .ssh
```

This resolved this instance of the problem.

Comment: I have been searching for three days for this answer!  It wasn't until I ran stat on the authorized keys file that I noticed an SELinux context on the file.  I compared it to an authorized keys file for a different user and noticed the difference!  Thank you, Greg!

Comment: One additional point I discovered:  If you subsequently run restorecon on this .ssh directory, you will lose the changes you made with the chcon command.  You need to also add a policy that will reapply the context properly upon a filesystem relabel.  I did this with the following command: semanage fcontext -a -t ssh_home_t "/path/to/service/home/.ssh(/.*)?".  (Be sure to use the full path.)

Comment: Corrected command:  semanage fcontext -a -t ssh_home_t "/path/to/service/home/\.ssh(/.*)?"

Answer (score 1):

I  had also this same issue, the proposed solution above did not solve the case for me. To summarise instructions abowe together:

1. Check following logfile on target system for possible details of errors: /var/log/secure
2. Permission of files in users ~/.ssh directory should be 600 and files should be owned By "user:group"
3. Permission of ~/.ssh directory should be 700 and owned By "user:group"
4. Permission of home directory of user ie. "~" (="~/.ssh/..") should be 755. If permissions are f.ex 775, ssh key autenthication failed in my system.

br
bruno

Comment: Did this instruction solve the case for you? Or is it just a compilation?

Answer (score 0):

The above answer is quite good, I have an addition & a suggestion. The addition is in line 2 below, as home directory permissions not be more permissive than rwxr-x--- for ssh key authentication.

```
cd ~
chmod g-w,o-rwx .
chmod 700 .ssh
cd .ssh
chmod 600 *
chmod 644 authorized_keys
chmod 644 known_hosts
chmod 644 config
restorecon -R -v ../.ssh
```

The suggestion is to make use of the -vv option when testing.

Comment: You probably mean ``o-rwx``, not ``u-rwx`` :)

Comment: Good catch! I have a recurring mnemonic issue with 'u' and 'o' in the chmod/chown commands. 'o' is 'other', not 'owner'!